# SCSS Function encoding different on local vs Prod

Tags: sass, bigcommerce, stenciljs, scss-functions

I have the following SCSS function:

```
  $data-svg-prefix: 'data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,';
  @if 'color' != type-of($color) {
    @warn 'The requested color - "' + $color + '" - was not recognized as a Sass color value.';
    @return null;
  }

  @if map-has-key($icons, $icon) {
    $icon: map-get($icons, $icon);
    $placeholder: '%%COLOR%%';
    $data-uri: str-replace(url($data-svg-prefix + $icon), $placeholder, $color);

    @return str-replace($data-uri, '#', '%23');
  }

  @warn 'The requested icon - "' + $icon + '" - is not defined in the $icons map.';
  @return null;
}
```

The str-replace function is:

```
  $index: str-index($string, $search);

  @if $index {
    @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1) + $replace +
      str-replace(
        str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)),
        $search,
        $replace
      );
  }

  @return $string;
}
```

When the code is used locally it works fine returning:

```
url('data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,<svg width="10" height="11" viewBox="0 0 10 11" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect y="5.044" width="10" height="1.364" rx=".682" fill="%23ffffff"/><rect x="4.091" y="10.953" width="10" height="1.364" rx=".682" transform="rotate(-90 4.09 10.953)" fill="%23ffffff"/></svg>')" fill="%23ffffff"/></svg>)
```

But for some reason, when it's pushed to prod it returns:

```
url('data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,<svg width="10" height="11" viewBox="0 0 10 11" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect y="5.044" width="10" height="1.364" rx=".682" fill="%23ffffff/><rect x="4.091" y="10.953" width="10" height="1.364" rx=".682" transform="rotate(-90 4.09 10.953)" fill=%23ffffff"/></svg>')" fill=%23ffffff"/></svg>)
```

As you can see the second fill="%23ffffff is missing the closing ".

This is on a big commerce website if that helps?

The original icon file is:

```
<svg width="10" height="11" viewBox="0 0 10 11" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect y="5.044" width="10" height="1.364" rx=".682" fill="%%COLOR%%"/><rect x="4.091" y="10.953" width="10" height="1.364" rx=".682" transform="rotate(-90 4.09 10.953)" fill="%%COLOR%%"/></svg>
```